# SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers() not finding installed language

Tags: .net, windows, localization, speech-recognition

I am developing a .NET 4.8 WPF application in WIN 10 PRO, I have two languages installed in Speech Recognition tab and one of them is also in the Language tab:

[image]

[image]

When I execute `System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()` it only retrieves the first language (US-us).

On the other hand, Cortana correctly finds and uses the Italian speech recognition engine.

I already found answers to supposed similar problems but none of them seems to be my case: [Windows 10 Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902274/windows-10-speech-recognition), [SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers returns No recognizer installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856798/speechrecognitionengine-installedrecognizers-returns-no-recognizer-installed).

Could anyone explain step by step how to install a speech recognizer that can be found by `System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()`?

Thanks in advance