# SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers doesn't find all languages

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition

My goal is to make a very simple speech recognition app in VB.NET, using **System.Speech v4.8** (imported in the app references).

The Windows 10 original language is the **Italian** one. I have added the **en-En** and **en-US** ones.

[image]

But if I run this routine:

```
 For Each ri As RecognizerInfo In SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers
    Debug.Write(ri.Culture.ToString)
 Next
```

The result is:

en-GB en-US (the original Win10 language is missing)

How can I set the italian lang in:

```
 Private WithEvents MainEngine As SpeechRecognitionEngine
 MainEngine = New SpeechRecognitionEngine(New CultureInfo("it-IT"))
```

and the related Grammar

```
 GrammarBuilder = New Choices(Words)
 Grammar = New Grammar(GrammarBuilder) With {
        .Name = Name,
        .Enabled = True
    }
 MainEngine.LoadGrammar(Grammar)
```

if this lang is not detected from System.Speech and **WHY** the ORIGINAL lang is not found?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902274/windows-10-speech-recognition

Comment: My app is a WinForms one, not WPF. Could be that the Italian language is not supported from the System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEngine, but online I cannot find a possible list of SpeechRecognitionEngine supported languages.